How to store tuples in Memgraph?
I have a design question regarding the best approach to store tuples of values, specifically for position (x, y, z), rotation, and scaling in Memgraph. I have an RPG node that is linked to an ACTOR node using the relationship HAS_ACTOR:
RPG -> HAS_ACTOR -> ACTOR

I am thinking about creating a Vector node to store the tuples (x, y, z) for position, rotation, and scaling. But this would also require creating two additional services (one for the node and one for the relationship) and handling transactions involving multiple nodes and relationships.
Is creating a separate Vector node the optimal approach for storing these tuples?

If you are storing data to Nodes, you will have redundancy (more memory usage in your graph) but will have access to faster queries from (X,Y,Z) data points if it becomes more important.
Fewer nodes and edges, less memory, and less flexibility.
Ask yourself a question will you ever run queries based on position? If the graph scale is low, the matter of this question is more of a preference, on bigger graphs, it makes a difference.
